# Android: fragments with RecyclerView orientation change error

Tags: android, android-orientation, android-recyclerview

I am using Sliding tabs in my app and I have 2 fragments with a view pager.Inside a fragment there is a recycler view also.

**Categories fragment**

```
public class Categories extends Fragment{
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    if (cat == null) {
        cat = inflater.inflate(R.layout.categories, container, false);
    } else {
        ((ViewGroup) cat.getParent()).removeAllViews();
    }
     catData = new ArrayList<>();

    if(mRecyclerView == null) {
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) cat.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
    }else{
        ((ViewGroup) mRecyclerView.getParent()).removeAllViews();
    }
    return mRecyclerView;

}

 Handler handler = new Handler();

Runnable mStatusChecker = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        GetCategoriesTask access = new GetCategoriesTask();
        access.execute();
        //this function can change value of mInterval.
        handler.postDelayed(mStatusChecker, 10000);
    }
};


private class GetCategoriesTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<CategoryData>> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

    }

    //task is running in background
    @Override
    protected ArrayList<CategoryData> doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

        ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();
        String baseAddress = "url";
        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(ServiceHandler.GET,baseAddress);

        if(jsonStr != null){
            try{
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                JSONArray data = jsonObj.getJSONArray("data");

                catData.clear();
                for(int i = 0;i < data.length();i++){
                    JSONObject c = data.getJSONObject(i);
                    String categoryName = c.getString("category");

                    catData.add(new CategoryData(categoryName));
                }
                return catData;

            }catch (JSONException ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);
        return null;
    }

    //after executing background task, this method will execute.
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<CategoryData> data) {

        if(!notifier) {
            adapter = new CategoryRecyclerViewAdapter(getContext(), data);
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            notifier = true;
        }
        else{                
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "changed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();     
    mStatusChecker.run();

}
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(final Bundle outState) {
    // super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    handler.removeCallbacks(mStatusChecker);

}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    handler.removeCallbacks(mStatusChecker);

}
@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();        
    handler.removeCallbacks(mStatusChecker);
}}
```

**Discover Fragment**

I have only the oncreate method.

```
public class Discover extends Fragment{

public View v;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    if (v == null) {
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.categories, container, false);
    } else {
        ((ViewGroup) v.getParent()).removeAllViews();
    }
    return v;
}
```

The problem is when I change the orientation of the app it gives an exception and displays the message "unfortunately ezycity has stopped".When I click the ok button app restarts again and work normally.

**logcat**

```
08-26 10:17:25.954    4452-4452/com.ezycity.seneru.ezycity E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.ezycity.seneru.ezycity, PID: 4452
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ezycity.seneru.ezycity/com.ezycity.seneru.ezycity.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3950)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:151)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1309)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:3936)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3786)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.addView(ViewPager.java:1342)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3727)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3700)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1032)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1197)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1179)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:1991)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:165)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:507)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1236)
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6006)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2288)
```

So how I solve this problem?

Comment: what's setting to your activity in manifest file?

Comment: I have this code in my manifest

Comment: android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|mcc|mnc"

Comment: Please debug your code and find out which of the fragments causes the problem. In the meantime i'll post an other problem which may cause this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So lets take a look at this piece of code:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup    container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    if (cat == null) {
        cat = inflater.inflate(R.layout.categories, container, false);
    } else {
        (   (ViewGroup) cat.getParent()).removeAllViews();
    }
     catData = new ArrayList<>();

    if(mRecyclerView == null) {
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) cat.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
    }else{
        ((ViewGroup) mRecyclerView.getParent()).removeAllViews();
    }
    return mRecyclerView;

}
```

At first you are inflating `cat` which is not attatched to the root, due to the last parameter. That is correct.

Then you are searching for `mRecyclerView` in `cat`. This also means the parent of `mRecyclerView` is cat.

After that you are returning `mRecyclerView`.
So the pager is trying to add `mRecyclerView` to a page, but `mRecyclerView` already has a parent (cat).

---

**So the solution for this fragment might be:**

instead of:

```
 return mRecyclerView;
```

use:

```
return cat;
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your support. I figured out what went wrong.It was a problem in my layout.Any way thanks for trying to help. :)